# Data from API call doesn't reach 1st time in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

I have a getState() API call when I select city. getState API has request params .i.e cityId. But there is some error on the 1st call. 1st call data show on 2nd call. 2nd call data shows on 3rd call. I used Vue multiselect for Dropdown. Now I want the first time to run this API instantly and I can't get this to work properly.

```js
<script>
  import VueMultiselect from "vue-multiselect";
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      cityId: "",
      selectedCity: "",
      cities: [],
      option: [],
      option1: [],
      selectedState: "",
      selectedCountry: "",
    };
  },
  getCity() {
    this.axios
      .get(this.baseURL + "cities", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.cities = response.data.data;
        console.warn(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
    this.apiLoaded = true;
  },
  getStates() {
    this.cityId = this.selectedCity.id;
    this.axios
      .get(this.baseURL + "states", {
        params: {
          id: this.cityId,
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.option = response.data.data.option;
        this.option1 = response.data.data.option1;
        console.warn(response.data.data.option);
        console.warn(response.data.data.option1);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    this.apiLoaded = true;
  },
},
components: {
    VueMultiselect,
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getCity();
    this.token = "token updated";
    console.warn(this.token);
  },
}; 
</script> 
<style src = "vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.css" > < /style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="mb-5 mr-16">
  <label class="text-lg font-bold mb-1.5" for="city">City<span class="text-jobRed">*</span></label>
                                  <VueMultiselect
                                    class="
                                      mt-1.5
                                      w-72
                                      shadow-smNew
                                      rounded-xl
                                      py-4
                                      pl-4
                                      text-lg
                                    "
                                    v-model="selectedCity"
                                    tag-placeholder="Add this as new city"
                                    placeholder="Search or add a city"
                                    label="city_name"
                                    track-by="id"
                                    :options="cities"
                                    :multiple="false"
                                    :taggable="true"
                                    @tag="addCity"
                                    @select="getStates()"
                                  ></VueMultiselect>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="mb-5 mr-16">
                                  <label
                                    class="text-lg font-bold mb-1.5"
                                    for="state"
                                    >State<span class="text-jobRed"
                                      >*</span
                                    ></label
                                  >
                                  <VueMultiselect
                                    class="
                                      mt-1.5
                                      w-72
                                      shadow-smNew
                                      rounded-xl
                                      py-4
                                      pl-4
                                      text-lg
                                    "
                                    v-model="selectedState"
                                    tag-placeholder="Add this as new state"
                                    placeholder="Search or add a state"
                                    label="state_name"
                                    track-by="state_name"
                                    :options="option"
                                    :multiple="false"
                                    :taggable="true"
                                    @tag="addState"
                                  ></VueMultiselect>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="mb-5 mr-16">
                                  <label
                                    class="text-lg font-bold mb-1.5"
                                    for="country"
                                    >Country<span class="text-jobRed"
                                      >*</span
                                    ></label
                                  >
                                  <VueMultiselect
                                    class="
                                      mt-1.5
                                      w-72
                                      shadow-smNew
                                      rounded-xl
                                      py-4
                                      pl-4
                                      text-lg
                                    "
                                    v-model="selectedCountry"
                                    tag-placeholder="Add this as new country"
                                    placeholder="Search or add a country"
                                    label="country_name"
                                    track-by="country_name"
                                    :options="option1"
                                    :multiple="false"
                                    :taggable="true"
                                    @tag="addCountry"
                                  ></VueMultiselect>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please, attach also the code of VueMultiselect.vue file

Comment: @Dmitrii  vue-multiselect.js.org here, is the documentation of Vue Multiselect

Comment: Please, help me to solve this error.